# setting up a UDP server and client using netty

Tags: networking, udp, netty

Netty is really well documented when it comes to TCP, but I wanted to try a simple UDP server-client example and didn't find any good code out there. (mostly mailing lists and users with allegedly buggy code)

Anyone care to provide some simple example? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this will help you

https://github.com/normanmaurer/javamagazin-netty-ws/tree/master/src/main/java/me/normanmaurer/javamagazin/netty/examples/ws

It also bootstrap a simple udp server